# Setting environment path variable in bashrc not testing at command line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand setting variables in .bashrc and .bash-profile.

If I add something to my .bashrc, like this

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export MMMM_HOME=/appl #added
#. ~/inits.bsh         #added
. /appl/etc/mmmm.env   #added
```

How can I check that it's set properly? I tried opening a new putty session, I tried typing bash, I tried at the command line `[-z "$MMMM_HOME"] && echo "empty" || echo "Not empty"` #-z: command not found...

I tried `which MMMM_HOME` and `which $MMMM_HOME` at the command line.

I googled it.  I'm not sure about this...does anyone have any info?  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: Do you 81) just want to test whether `MMMM_HOME` is set, or (2) if it is set and not empty, or (3) if it is defined in your environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two spaces are missing in your test. Here's the command with the right bash syntax:

```
[ -z "$MMMM_HOME" ] && echo "empty" || echo "Not empty"
```

Comment: I found out echo $MMMM_HOME works to show it's contents too.  Thanks!